# Flow of vector field

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-analysis

For my PDE class I have to find the flow of the following vector field

$$\mathbf{F}: \mathbb{R}^2-\{0\} \to \mathbb{R}^2, \mathbf{F}(x_1,x_2) = \frac{1}{r}(-x_2, x_1)$$
where $$r = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2}}$$

I **know** that I can find the flow of this vector field by setting

$$\mathbf{\dot{x}}(t) = \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x}(t)) $$ which yields the equations

$$ \dot{x_1} = \frac{1}{r} (-x_2) $$

and $$ \dot{x_2} = \frac{1}{r} x_1 $$ or in matrix notation 
$$ \dot{\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix}} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -\frac{1}{r} \\ \frac{1}{r} & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix} $$

Normally, I would solve this quite easily with an exponential ansatz. But here, $r$ itself depends on $x$ and $y$ which makes the matrix nonlinear. Thus I have no idea how to approach this?

Comment: $F(x) \cdot x = 0$, $|F(x)|=|x|^2=x \cdot x$ helps?

Comment: No, what do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hint is valuable: the integral curves are always orthogonal to the position vector: it points to the idea the curves are circles and the factor $1/r$ doesn't change this.

If we need only the <strike>integral curves</strike> orbits, we can calculate $\dfrac{\dot x_2}{\dot x_1}=\dfrac{d x_2}{d x_1}$

$\dfrac{d x_2}{d x_1}=-\dfrac{x_1}{x_2}$

$x_2=\pm\sqrt{c_1-x_1^2}$

Corresponding to circles centered at $(0,0)$

**Added**

Anyway, it's interesting solve the system for $t$ as it explains the factor $1/r$ when compared with the solution for the system without this factor.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Do you also know how I could solve the ODE system as alternative solution? And how does solving the system for t explains the factor $\frac{1}{r}$? What do you mean by that?

Comment: Having the graph the hard part is done. We have a relation between $x_1$ and $x_2$ to play with. First $c'_1\sqrt{c_1}=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}=1/r$

$$\dot x_1=-c'_1\sqrt{c_1-x_1^2}\implies x_1(t)=-c'_1\sin(c'_1(c_2+t))$$

etc.

Comment: I am not sure now why I said we can find a reason for $1/r$. Anyway, the solution is surprisingly similar with and without.

Comment: Thank you so far! Your answer and comments were really helpful. Though I think that you have a typo in your comment above. Shouldn't it be $c_1' = \frac{1}{\sqrt{c_1}}$? One more question: Why do you choose the positive square root, i.e. why $\dot{x}_1 = -c_1'\sqrt{c_1 - x_1^2}$ and not $\dot{x}_1 = c_1'\sqrt{c_1 - x_1^2}$?

Comment: The system was not completely solved. I started with the positive root for the remaining task of relating the integration constants for the equations to fit coherently.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying one other thing? What exactly are the integral curves and what is flow then? Are  $y = \pm \sqrt{C - x}$ the integral curves? As you wrote, when you insert those identities in the actual equations of the vector field you get separable ODEs that one can solve easily. Are the resulting functions the $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ together the flow of the vector field?

Comment: My bad. I used the terminology in a loose fashion. I calculated the orbit first, so is, the image in $\mathbb R^2$ of the integral curves. Integral curves are the flow in this context.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58042/discussion-between-rafa-budria-and-taufi).

Comment: Okay! I wrote you there.

Comment: $x(t),y(t)$ are the integral curves and $y=f(x)$ the orbit.